# Can I change the server address when committing using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ip-address, local

The funny thing about laptops is that you can take them places.

I am just starting out using a subversion server at home. Last night I checked out a project using my local IP address at home (192.168.X.X), and now I am elsewhere and I would like to commit some changes back.

The problem is that TortoiseSVN seems to be locked into the address I checked out from (192.168.X.X). I googled around and checked the documentation, but no luck so far. I can't be the first person on Earth to have this problem, so does anyone know if it's possible at all to change the target repository's address before trying to commit?

Comment: Do you use a proxy which is not configured on your laptop? afaik the only thing that matters to tortoise is the address of the repository

Comment: @fiscblog 192.168.x IPs are private, non-routable addresses. If he's using that "at home" then it's not accessible from anywhere else without an external IP and port forwarding - which would necessitate a relocate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to perform a **relocate** to point your WC at the correct server URL.

[For TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html)

[For the command-line](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html)

But this will only work if your server at home is accessible from outside your home network.

Comment: Thank you thank you! This is exactly what I needed! I guess I couldn't find it in the documentation because it speaks of the server address having changed, rather than the server address being hidden behind a NAT.